# How To Print A Key In A Dictionary With A For Loop

Tags: python, dictionary

How do I print out the key of a dictionary within a for loop? With the code below, I know how to print out the values of the dictionary, "2, 3, 4, 5" but how would I go about printing the key "1"?

```
dictionary = {}
nums = "1 2 3 4 5"
splitList = nums.split()
dictionary[splitList[0]] =[(splitList[1]), (splitList[2]), (splitList[3]), (splitList[4])]

print(dictionary)

for i in dictionary:
    print(dictionary[i])
    print(dictionary[i][1])
#How do I print the key?
```

Comment: `i` is the key.

Comment: yeah, just `print(i)` to print the key(s).

Answer (score 0):

For reference:

```
#Assume we have some dictionary named dict

for key in dict.keys():
    print(key) #prints the keys of the dict

for value in dict.values():
    print(value) #prints the values of the dict

for key, value in dict.items():
    print(key, value) #prints the keys and values of the dict
```

For more information on Python dicts see https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/dict/